# Template argument deduction for 'char*'

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have below function (Just for reproducing the issue):

```
template <typename KeyT>
void func(const KeyT cptr) {
  std::cout << typeid(KeyT).name() << std::endl;
}
```

I would like to call this with a string literal, like below:

```
func<char*>("literal");
```

But, I end up getting below warning:

```
warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wc++11-compat-deprecated-writable-strings]
```

I have a specific need to use `char*` as my Key type and I was expecting `TAD` to consider the `param type` as `const char*` in whole as I am not taking it by reference.

The warning comes with both `clang` and `g++` compilers.

How is the `param type` being deduced here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `cptr` ends up being a const pointer-to-char (`char *const`), not a pointer to const char.

Comment: @melpomene How did that end up like that ?

Comment: Your declaration says `cptr` must be `const`, and you instantiate `KeyT` with `char *`. So `cptr` is a const KeyT (with KeyT = pointer-to-char).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I was expecting `TAD` to consider the param type as const char* ...
>   How is the param type being deduced here ?

```
template <typename KeyT>
void func(const KeyT cptr)
```

Note that `const` is the qualifier on `KeyT` itself, it means if `KeyT` is a pointer, then `cptr` will be a const pointer, not a pointer to const.

`"literal"` is sring literal with type `const char[8]`, which might decay to `const char*`. Then `KeyT` might be deduced as `const char*`, then the type of `cptr` will be `const char* const`.

You're specifying the template argument type as `char*`, then makes `cptr` a `char* const`. But from C++11, converting a string literal to `char*` implicitly is not allowed since literals are `const`.

Why do you need the template parameter type to be `char*`? To modify it inside the function? Note that modifying a string literal will lead to UB. You could pass a char array to it, like:

```
char my_chararray[] = "literal";
func<char*>(my_chararray); // or just func(my_chararray);
```

Comment: `Why you need the template parameter type to be char*? To modify it inside the function?`. No, this is just an example that I have shown. I am actually using `char*` as a key type to some self made container which would be copying the provided literal into the containers data structure. I wanted to try it without using `remove_const` / `decay` traits.

Comment: @Arunmu If you won't modify it, using `const char*` will be fine (specify the template argument as `const char*` or don't specify at all). If not, you have to do something more like my answer showed.

Comment: yeah, thats what it looks like. I need to perhaps rethink on my interface.

Answer (score 8):

There is no *deduction* here: you have explicitly stated that the template parameter is `char*`.

What you're missing is that parameter substitution is not a text search-and-replace: it actually follows the logical rules for the type system. `const KeyT cptr` declares a `const` instance of the type `KeyT` — when `KeyT` is `char*`, the parameter declaration becomes `char *const cptr`.